# C# out keyword meaning and does it have an equivalent in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, out

I'm trying to convert this C# method into PHP. What does the out in the second parameter mean?

```
public static bool Foo(string name, out string key)
```

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't know why you'd use a out-parameter. All out and ref parameters can be replace by simple returns. This provides more control of the output.

Comment: @GroundZero ...it already returns another type.

Comment: @J.Steen Then use an object to return ... If you have a method which should return a first and a last name, use a Name object which included these 2 strings. This solves the ugly code using an out and a return. First of all, using out/ref should be avoided and you should definitly try avoiding both out/ref and return

Comment: @GroundZero: Int.TryParse is a good example when out can be a good option. However, the method could indeed return a type that would put together the bool and the int variables, but the former approach seems more right here.

Comment: @GroundZero And if you're doing, say, a TryParse method? Then it's not really a good choice of solution. It's a matter of taste and convention, really. =)

Comment: I don't think this is a dup of that question. He asked how to transate out to php

Comment: You cannot just return something when you are not sure that you will find it. Returning null is a bad design decision and so the best way to do this is to set desired output as parameter to a function and it's return make a boolean that will indicate whatever data is found or not. (answers to previous comments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation<sup>ref</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public static function foo($str, &$key)
                                 ^
                                 | Pass by reference
```

Please consider that in C# you must set a value in the calling method when using `out` and *sadly* you can't directly translate that into PHP.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: he asked how to convert that to PHP... And it's pretty self explanatory I believe.

Comment: @llnk: If it would be self explanatory he wouldn't aks the qustion and you wouldn't equate `ref` with `out` ;-)

Comment: It's not self explanatory. The question *mainly* asks about what does the `out` keyword mean. The conversion is secondary. *also*, as someone who doesn't know C#, I have no idea what the `out` parameter mean, so your question has (had) little value to me.

Comment: @Madara: I have wrote pass by reference, I believe pass by reference is self explanatory... don't you think?

Comment: @llnk: Only from what I see, `out` != `pass by reference` or is it? I can remove my downvote after that last edit. But look at your first revision and think hard on whether my downvote was unjustified.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Ok I appreciate constructive discussion :)

Answer (score 5):

The `out` keyword specifies that the parameter must be assigned to by the called method, and the value assigned will be passed back to the calling method. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) for more info.

I don't think PHP has an equivalent for the required assignment behavior, but if you are converting the method body, and maintain that behavior internally, you should be able to convert it to a regular pass by reference parameter and maintain the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny bit of Googeling brought me to this site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

As you know, a parameter is a copy of a variable.
This means you won't actually change the variable itself.
For example:

```
<?php
    function foo($bar) {
        $bar++;
    }

    $bar = 5;  // $bar = 5
    foo($bar); // $bar = 6

    echo $bar; // $bar = 5
?>
```

Whilst this piece of code will actually change the given variable, as is uses reference.

```
<?php
    function foo(&$bar) {
        $bar++;
    }

    $bar = 5;  // $bar = 5
    foo($bar); // $bar = 6

    echo $bar; // $bar = 6 now
?>
```

NOTE: this is not an exact PHP-version of the out-parameter you have in C#